# Integration of polynomials given in a factorized form

Tags: calculus

How can I directly integrate the expression
$ \int (2x^2-1)^6 dx $ without expanding the expression?

Comment: Because you do not have the $f'(x)$ inside the integral you can integrate per parts $\int 1 \cdot f(x)^6$

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{gather*}
I_n=\int(2x^2-1)^ndx\\
\implies I_n=\int1\cdot(2x^2-1)^ndx\\
\implies I_n=x\cdot(2x^2-1)^n-\int x\cdot\Big(n(2x^2-1)^{n-1}\cdot 4x\Big)dx\\
\implies I_n=x\cdot(2x^2-1)^n-2n\int(2x^2-1)^n+(2x^2-1)^{n-1}dx\\
\implies \boxed{I_n=(x-2n)(2x^2-1)^n-2nI_5}
\end{gather*}